# spring validation annotation for compulsory and non-compulsory fields

Tags: spring, validation

```
     @NotEmpty
private String cname;
public String getCname() {
    return cname;
}
public void setCname(String cname) {
    this.cname = cname;
}

private String cdescription;
public String getCdescription() {
    return cdescription;
}
public setCdescription(String cdescription) {
    if(cdescription.length()>0){
    this.cdescription = cdescription;}
```

In the above code,Cname is a compulsory field and Cdescription is a non-compulsory field but it has to be validated.Cname is working fine. I want to know how I can validate Cdescription w/o making it compulsory

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement You can use different annotations of javax.validation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html
Also Hibernate validation will help you.@NotBlank , @NotNull , @NotEmpty various types of annotation available in hibernate-validator jar.

Comment: Thanks man for reply.But I'm already using above annotations to my advantage in my code.As I said Cdescription has to be a non-compulsory field which can be left blank or he can enter only alphabets.I want to ensure both the conditions are met.Thanks again